# Elasticsearch: Aggregate distinct values in array

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch to store click traffic and each row includes topics of the page which has been visited. A typical row looks like:

```
{
  "date": "2017-09-10T12:26:53.998Z",
  "pageid": "10263779",
  "loc_ll": [
    -73.6487,
    45.4671
  ],
  "ua_type": "Computer",
  "topics": [
    "Trains",
    "Planes",
    "Electric Cars"
  ]
}
```

I want each `topics` to be a keyword so if I search for `cars` nothing will be returned. Only `Electric Cars` would return a result.

I also want to run a distinct query on all topics in all rows so I have a list of all topics used.

Doing this on a `pageid` would look like like the following, but I am unsure how to approach this for the `topics` array.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": pageid,
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach to querying and getting the available terms looks fine. Probably you should check your mapping. If you get results for `cars` this looks as your mapping for `topics` is an analyzed string (e.g. type `text` instead of `keyword`). So please check your mapping for this field.

```
PUT keywordarray
{
  "mappings": {
    "item": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "topics": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this sample data

```
POST keywordarray/item
{
  "id": 123,
  "topics": [
    "first topic", "second topic", "another"
  ]
}
```

and this aggregation:

```
GET keywordarray/item/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "topics": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "topics"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

will result in this:

```
"aggregations": {
  "topics": {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
    "buckets": [
      {
        "key": "another",
        "doc_count": 1
      },
      {
        "key": "first topic",
        "doc_count": 1
      },
      {
        "key": "second topic",
        "doc_count": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `keyword` was it, I was mapping it as text thinking that `keyword` for concatenate the array.

Answer (score 1):

It is very therapeutic asking on SO. Simply changing the mapping type to `keyword` allowed me to achieve what I needed.

A part of me thought that it would concatenate the array into a string. But it doesn't

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "view": {
      "properties": {
        "topics": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and a search query like

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": pageid,
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Will return a distinct list of all elements in a fields array.